# getting error while creating a single table instead of create_all

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a table on demand.

```
def create_host_table(name):
    """Create host server status table.

    Arguments:
        name (str): name of the host.
    """
    class HostMachineStatus(Base):
        __tablename__ = '{0}{1}{2}'.format(HOST_TABLE_PREFIX, name, HOST_TABLE_SUFFIX)
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        status = Column(String(7)) # online or offline
        datemodified = Column('datemodified', TIMESTAMP, server_default=text(
            'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
            )
        )
        datecreated= Column('datecreated', TIMESTAMP)
        status_time_delta = ('status_time_delta', TIMESTAMP) # duration how long was online or offline.
    table_name = HostMachineStatus.__tablename__
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine, Base.metadata.tables[table_name],checkfirst=True)
```

but the above code throws error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server_status.py", line 97, in <module>
    main()
  File "server_status.py", line 93, in main
    create_host_table(host)
  File "server_status.py", line 71, in create_host_table
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine, Base.metadata.tables[table_name],checkfirst=True)
  File "/home/rock64/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 4316, in create_all
    ddl.SchemaGenerator, self, checkfirst=checkfirst, tables=tables
  File "/home/rock64/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2049, in _run_visitor
    conn._run_visitor(visitorcallable, element, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rock64/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1618, in _run_visitor
    visitorcallable(self.dialect, self, **kwargs).traverse_single(element)
  File "/home/rock64/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 138, in traverse_single
    return meth(obj, **kw)
  File "/home/rock64/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 754, in visit_metadata
    [t for t in tables if self._can_create_table(t)]
TypeError: 'Table' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation (emphasis mine):

> tables – Optional **list** of Table objects, which is a subset of the total tables in the MetaData (others are ignored).

So the issue is that you are passing a single table, not a list of tables. (The "is not iterable" in the error output is also a strong hint here.) Try this instead:

```py
Base.metadata.create_all(engine, [Base.metadata.tables[table_name]], checkfirst=True)
```

Comment: cool thanks, earlier I thought its `Base.metadata.tables` accepting multiple table names